# Get real error from backup job failure instead of backup terminating abnormaly

Tags: sql-server-2016, backup, error-handling

I've had log backup jobs fail for a few different reasons lately.  When I go to the job it tells me backup terminated abnormally.  However, when I run the backup script in SSMS it will tell me the real reason such as the destination drive being out of space.  I put a try catch around my command but it gives the same error I see from the job.  How do I capture the error that SSMS is providing?

Comment: Are you looking at the Job Step's details for the error when it fails?...that's usually more detailed than the Job's details, in the History window.

Comment: Yes.  Although more verbose than what I've written, since it gives the percentage it got through, It still amounts to the same error.  Backup log is terminating abnormally.  The statement has been terminated.  The step failed.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the job history showing this? It should show both errors (the inner and outer) in the job history.